# does facebook post api fied description support html

Tags: facebook

Will the description field support html tags

```
$facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", array(
    message => $des,
    picture => $img,
    link => $link,
    caption => $title ,
    description =>$desc
));
```

I would looking to have description as

```
$desc="hai to <strong>All</strong><br>I am on the nextline";
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, facebook doesn't interpret formatting in the description field (simply shows as them you send it), and you can't place newlines. If you want to add extra links to the message you can use the properties field of the [Post object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).